# How do I point my domain to my website/ip adress

Tags: dns, xampp

I havve recently set up a website, I've forwarded it to my Ip and I'm able to access it.
However I have also bought a domain which I would like to use for my website which I host through my own pc using xampp.

From what I understand I would need to create a dns server, but do still not understand how to do it.

So my question is, How do I point my newly bought domain to my website which is being hosted using xampp?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't set up your own DNS server on your homeline, use a 3rd party provider instead that is 'always online'. Typically your registrar (the place where you bought your domain) can do this for you relatively easy or for a small fee. This allows your DNS to be always available, which is important if you want to for example receive mail.

When you have that done, point the A record of your domain + the www.yourdomain to your XAMPP environment and configure XAMPP. Do this by adding a virtualhost for your domain and you are good to go!

Comment: Thanks for the respond
My domain registrar do not support this function :/.
Is there any other way, or how do I setup a dns server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third party DNS provider(for free). Choose one, register the DNS zone with it, create the A records as ranieuwe said:

```
@ A your.servers.ip.address
www A your.servers.ip.address
```

and the NS records, if they are not added by default.

```
@ NS dnsX.thisDNSprovider.com
```

After that go to your registrar and change the nameservers of the domain to point to the servers from your NS records (dnsX.thisDNSprovider.com). It should be okay in a few hours.